# Как зафиксировать несколько изображений вместе?

Tags: разметка, изображения, масштабирование

Нужно наложить несколько картинок на одну и сделать так, чтоб при масштабировании экрана картинки фиксировались вместе, а не разъезжались кто куда

```
<style>
    .background
    {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url('/image/roket.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .logo
    {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url('/image/tennis1.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        width: 60%;
        height: 70%;
        /*left: 20px;*/
        /*top: 150px;*/
    }
    .logo2
    {
        position: fixed;
        background-image: url('/image/batut1.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center right;
        width: 60%;
        height: 70%;
        left: 20%;
        /*top: 150px;*/
    }
</style>
<div class="center-block">
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo2"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. и как сделать, чтобы эти картинки были по центру страницы?